# make autocompletetextview look like edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I am using an AutoCompleteTextView ([RobotoAutoCompleteTextView](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-RobotoTextView/blob/master/robototextview/src/main/java/com/devspark/robototextview/widget/RobotoAutoCompleteTextView.java)) instead of an EditText. But I want the look and feel of an EditText: i.e. the underline that shows up at the bottom of an EditText. So how might I do that?

My question is a bit incomplete so let me clarify. In the Eclipse Graphical Layout the AutoCompleteTextView looks exactly like the EditText with the underline. But when I run the app in my Samsung Galaxy S5, the underline is gone. Instead I get an ugly box with some "#22000000" background. (Of course I am guessing at the exact hex of the background). So what I need is for the underline to always shows up no matter what device I am using: real phone, or just the Graphical Layout.

Comment: I have the same question.  I have an AutoCompleteTextView above a regular EditText, and both the underline and left margins are different between the two, which looks horrible.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Same question as well. Huawei P9/P10/P30 all have very distinct UI/UX differences between EditText AND Auto/Multi*TextView components.

Answer (score 2):

Try  this:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
 ...
 style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText" />
```

or this

```
<EditText
 ...
 style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"/>
```

Comment: Can you please provide full layout xml for better clarity?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used Android Studio for several years. Nevertheless, I am convinced that in my answer I have included all the necessary information to achieve the required effect (at least back then).