# EditText and AutoCompleteTextView text starts not on same position

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview, android-appcompat

I've a EditText and a AutoCompleteTextView and the text starts not on the same position which looks a bit strange.

I'm using appcompat v7 and I don't know if it's possible to fix this.
The line in the bottom is also different (so so bad as the text begin)

I also tried to style it like appcompat's EditText, but that doesn't look like that.

[image: I've a EditText and a AutoCompleteTextView and the text starts not on the same position which looks a bit strange.]

## Code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_berechnen"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_berechnen"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="@string/input_ipAdresse"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" >

    <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</EditText>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/input_snm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/Button_berechnen"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" />
```

Comment: It seems that AutoCompleteTextView is still using the ICS style, while EditText is using the new Material Design.

Comment: You can use `style="?android:editTextStyle"` to make it use the Material style.

Comment: that I tried before: line is black not turquoise or so and the text still starts on the same position

Comment: Have you find a solution for this? I have the same exact problem..!

Comment: not yet; android support library doesn't support it

Comment: Here is the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220058/make-autocompletetextview-look-like-edittext/28991759#28991759